# Flask : Unable to render Unicode Characters in Webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, unicode, flask-restful

I am trying to print devnagari (hindi) on a webpage using flask. However, on browsing to the webpage, the unicode I am passing is converted to a string.
Program -

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Text(Resource):
    def get(self):
        textInput = u'\u0960'
        return textInput

api.add_resource(Text, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output :

```
"\u0960"
```

Expected Output :

```
ॠ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Flask's *make_response* to return a response instance, it works fine:

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask, make_response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Text(Resource):
    def get(self):
        textInput = u'\u0960'
        return make_response(textInput)

api.add_resource(Text, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Great ! Worked Perfectly Fine however, now I am facing issues when I am trying to get the textInput from a form 
I changed my code to : 

@app.route("/getText", methods = ['POST'])
def post():
    textInput = request.form["data"]
    return render_template("text.html", text = textInput)

where I am sending the data via POST

Comment: Sounds like a new question is in order.

Comment: I think Nick K9 is right. That is an issue for another question. PS: Please don't forget to mark my answer "accepted" ;)

Comment: @ElisabethStrunk Here is a link to the new question -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60780228/opencv-and-flask-trying-to-send-detected-text-to-a-template-html-file